# Footer is not end of page when zooming out

Tags: html, css, footer

since i am learning CSS i am playing around a little, and i ran into this weird issue where the footer is not the end of the page.

Currently my Footer is like this:
If i move the whole div into the footer div, it doesn't show the full content since the footer sticks to the page, so i moved it above to be able to scroll the content, which works fine so far, however, as soon as i zoom out it creates more background below the footer.

```css
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: visible;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #666666;
}
/* Style for the navigation */
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;

}
/* Style the navigation links */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.3rem 1.3rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* Change color on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
.topnav a:not(.active){
  padding-bottom: (1.3rem + 6px);
}
.topnav .active:after{
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #cd650b;
  border-top-width: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  z-index: 101;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 0px;
  margin-top: 11px;
  margin-bottom: -21px;
}
.TopnavSecondBar {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #cd650b;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 10;
}
/* Triangle Shapes Start*/
.shapes {
    position: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
    background-color: #cd650b;
}
.boxesFooterBoxesBefore .st0, .boxesFooterBoxesAfter .st0 {
    fill: #cd650b;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
*, ::before, ::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    min-width: 0;
    }
.boxesFooterBoxes {
    color: #eee;
}
/* Content style */
.content {
/*   background-color: #d9d9d9; */
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
}
.button1 {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-style: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
.button2 {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-style: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
.button2:disabled{
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-style: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

/* Center Buttons */
.center {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;

}
.footerLinks:link, .footerLinks:visited {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.2rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;  
  margin-top: 0.452125rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.1rem;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
.footerLinks:hover, .footerLinks:active {
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  color: black;
}
.copyright {
  margin-top: 1px;
  font-size: .9525rem
}

/* Javascript message style */
.js{ 
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.converter {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.boxesFooterBoxesAfter {
  width: 101%;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
} 
.BottomNavSecondBar {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #cd650b;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto auto auto;
  z-index: 10;
}
.BottomNavThirdBar {
  height: 65.2125px;
  background-color: #333;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto auto auto;
  z-index: 10;
    text-align: center;
}
.AdditionalPartnerBefore, .st2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: -50px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.codebox {
    resize: none;
    border-style: solid;
}
/* Display button above text */
/*.btn i {
  display: block;
} */

.btn {
  width: 8.4rem;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #333;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1.7rem;
  margin: 0.3rem;
  font-size: 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid;
  border-color: #cd650b;
  border-width: 1px;
}
/* Darker background on mouse-over */
.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  border-color: #cd650b;
  border-width: 1px;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: transparent;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: auto;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 20rem;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.btn {
   max-width: 30%;
   margin: 5px;
}
.schmutz {
.footer {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    height: 170px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="./images/favicon.jpg">       <!--favicon-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" type="text/css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./button.css" type="text/css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./math.css" type="text/css"> 
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/763deb09da.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">                                                                        <!--UTF8 charset-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1">                      <!--responsive-->
<title>Schmutz</title>                                                                        <!--page title-->
</head>
<body>
  <noscript id="noscript" class="noscript">                              <!-- if Javascript is disabled -->
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content=0;url="nojs.php">
  </noscript>       <!-- redirect to nojs site -->
  <div class="topnav">
          <a href="./index.php"><b>Home</b></a>
          <a class="active" href="./configurator.php"><b>Configurator</b></a>
          <a href="./Trader.php"><b>Trader</b></a>
          <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://scum-forum.com/"><b>Forum</b></a>
  </div>
  <div class="TopnavSecondBar"></div>
  <div class="pageNavigationAfter">
    <svg version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="none" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1920 80" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1920 80;" xml:space="preserve">
        <g transform="translate(0.000000,80.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
    <path fill="#333" class="st1" d="M0 400 l0 -400 88 1 c48 0 4369 179 9602 398 l9515 399 -9602 1 -9603 1 0 -400z"></path>
        </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i> Basics</button>
    <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-car"></i> Vehicle</button>
    <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-dolly"></i> Items</button>
    <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Config</button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="a">
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox"> 
        <span class="slider"></span>
      </label>  testtesttesttest
      <div class="b">
        <label class="test" for="quantity">economy-reset-time-hours</label>
        <input class="number" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="-1" max="100"> 
        <label for="quantity"></label>
      </div>
      <div class="b">
        <label class="test" for="quantity">e</label>
        <input class="number" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="-1" max="100"> 
        <label for="quantity">testtesttesttesttesttest</label>
      </div>
      <div class="b">
        <label class="test" for="quantity">e</label>
        <input class="number" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="-1" max="100"> 
        <label for="quantity">testtesttesttesttesttest</label>
      </div>
      <div class="b">
        <label class="test" for="quantity">e</label>
        <input class="number" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="-1" max="100"> 
        <label for="quantity">testtesttesttesttesttest</label>
      </div>
      <div class="b">
        <label class="test" for="quantity">e</label>
        <input class="number" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="-1" max="100"> 
        <label for="quantity">testtesttesttesttesttest</label>
      </div>
      <div class="b">
        <label class="test" for="quantity">e</label>
        <input class="number" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="-1" max="100"> 
        <label for="quantity">testtesttesttesttesttest</label>
      </div>
      <div class="b">
        <label class="test" for="quantity">e</label>
        <input class="number" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="-1" max="100"> 
        <label for="quantity">testtesttesttesttesttest</label>
      </div>
      <div class="b">
        <label class="test" for="quantity">e</label>
        <input class="number" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="-1" max="100"> 
        <label for="quantity">testtesttesttesttesttest</label>
      </div>
      <div class="b">
        <label class="test" for="quantity">e</label>
        <input class="number" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="-1" max="100"> 
        <label for="quantity">testtesttesttesttesttest</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="schmutz">
    <div class="AdditionalPartnerBefore">
      <svg version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="none" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1920 80" style="max-width:100%; enable-background:new 0 0 1920 80;" xml:space="preserve">
      <!-- <svg version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="none" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" height="5rem" style="max-width:100%; enable-background:new 0 0 1920 80;" xml:space="preserve"> -->
        <g  transform="translate(0.000000,80.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
          <path fill="#333" class="st2" d="M9480 400 l-9485 -398 9603 -1 9602 -1 0 400 0 400 -117 -1 c-65 -1 -4386 -180 -9603 -399z"></path>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="BottomNavSecondBar"></div>
    <div class="BottomNavThirdBar">
      <a class="footerLinks" href="https://scum-forum.com/core/legal-notice/">Legal Notice</a>
      <a class="footerLinks" href="https://scum-forum.com/core/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a>
      <p class="copyright">&copy; test-test.com<p>
    </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Please post a [repro] for debugging details. As a side note, you should learn to use semantic tags such as `<footer>`. As they can do already 80% of the accessibility work by default.

Comment: Thank you, i inserted the full snippet, sorry i am still new to how this site works :(

Comment: you place the element `<div class="footer">` to the bottom of your viewport. However, that element itself is empty. You have to actually place the content inside that element.

Comment: When i do that, and i add more content to the page, it hides the content behind the footer and wont allow me to scroll down

Comment: yes because `position: fixed` moves an element out of flow. Either you should add a `margin-bottom` to the body equalling at least the height of the footer or use `position: sticky`

Comment: As soon as i make the footer sticky, it creates blank space below of it when scrolling down. however, when i leave it as fixed, i can create a margin-bottom, between the content and the footer, when i turn it to fixed, the margin doesn't do anything, i am so confused at this point

Comment: Got it to work, i honestly have no clue how lol, i moved anything in the footer, the position is still fixed, but this time it seemed to work with a margin on the body elements, even tho it didnt before, thank you for your help

Comment: probably a caching issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flex-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) to achieve a footer that stays at the bottom of the browser window when there isn't sufficient content to push it down. When there is sufficient content, the footer will be in a natural flow with the other elements and the page (including footer) will scroll as expected.

You can see how this works in [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/shainanigans-1472169587/pen/MWGPWwJ). (In the future, creating a minimal reproducible example in something like CodePen can help people debug your issue faster. You'll need to strip away as much as possible from your code so that only the essential parts that cause the issue remain.) I've marked the parts relevant to you, but, in summary:

- Set the CSS properties of `display: flex; flex-direction: column; min-height: 100vh;` on your `body` (or another element that wraps around your nav, main content, and footer)
- Wrap your main content in a wrapping container, like `main` and apply `flex-grow: 1`